# How to tell difference between JPEG and JPEG2000?

Tags: jpeg, jpeg2000

The question is: How can i tell two files apart? One coded with JPEG, another with JPEG2000.

I need format-specific file read/write functions, i can't find file encoding without reading it.
JPEG works fine right now, but JPEG func fails to open JPEG2000.
So i need to determine whether my file is JPG or JPEG2000.

Comment: You need to be a bit more specific about your environment - do you mean on Windows? Or within Javascript or node? Or at a Linux terminal? In PHP on OSX?

Comment: Windows. To read jpeg2000 i intend to use openjpeg.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [Digital Formats at Library of Congress](http://www.digitalpreservation.gov/formats/fdd/fdd000143.shtml), all JPEG 2000 files start with the following signature (also known as magic bytes or magic number):

```
00 00 00 0C 6A 50 20 20 0D 0A 87 0A
```

(The IANA record only lists the first 12, so I left the remainder out).

Normal [JPEG](http://www.digitalpreservation.gov/formats/fdd/fdd000018.shtml) files on the other hand, starts with:

```
FF D8 FF E0
```

Comparing these bytes, you should easily be able to tell them apart.